# Especificar color de la figura de la leyenda (pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Buen día señores, ando trabajando con matplotlib y tengo un problemita. Tengo un diagrama de dispersión (**plt.scatter**) donde los objetos tienen colores y formas. Normalmente cuando tienes una leyenda el color de los objetos en la leyenda se ajusta al que se muestra en la gráfica. Pero aquí **me lo pone azul** porque cada objeto tiene un color.

¿Existe alguna forma de modificar el color del objeto de la leyenda?

Estuve buscando en [matplotlib.org/[...]/matplotlib.pyplot.legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) y solo encontré labelcolor, facecolor y edgecolor; ningún método aplicaba al color del objeto.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a = [5, 6, 5.5, 7.3, 6.4, 7, 6.8, 5.8, 7.6]
b = [2, 3, 2.8, 4, 3.5, 3.9, 4.2, 3.9, 4.8]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

a_dots = plt.scatter(b, a, c=x, marker='o', label='y')
b_dots = plt.scatter(a, b, c=x, marker='s', label='z')

plt.title('Ejemplo')
plt.colorbar(a_dots)
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: Imagen de gráfico]

Comment: puedes asignarle un `edgecolors` que lo que hara es agregarle un borde del color que decidas ejemplo `edgecolors="red"`

Comment: Edgecolor no cambia el color de las figuritas de la leyenda, solo el borde de los objetos de la gráfica

Answer (score 0):

acá está modificado el color de la leyenda pero fijáte que se modifica a todo el gráfico tambien, no sé si eso es importante en tu gráfico aunque de acá ya tenés una idea de cómo pensarlo. espero te sírva.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9]
a = [5 , 6 , 5.5 , 7.3 , 6.4 , 7 , 6.8 , 5.8 , 7.6]
b = [2 , 3 , 2.8 , 4 , 3.5 , 3.9 , 4.2 , 3.9 , 4.8]


fig , ax = plt.subplots (figsize = (10 , 9) , dpi = 150)

a_dots = plt.scatter (b , a , x , color = 'r' , marker ='o' , label ='y')
b_dots = plt.scatter (a , b , x , color = 'g' , marker ='s' , label ='z')

plt.title ('ejemplo')
plt.colorbar (a_dots)
ax.legend (loc = 'upper left')
plt.show ()
```

así se vería ahora

[image: ejemplo]

Comment: Al especificar el color del grupo de objetos no puedo hacer el degradado de color